# How to set repeating alarm on week days[Day and Night], Week end in simple manner?

Tags: android, calendar, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I need to set on repeating alarm for my below cases,

```
Week Days[Day(8AM -8PM), Night(8PM -8AM)]
Week End
```

My Application mode changes during each period of time.

**I have used the below code to set an alarm for particular day[Monday].**

```
//Setting Alarm on Monday 8AM
Calendar alarmCalendar= Calendar.getInstance();
alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 2); 
alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 8);
alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, am);
```

Above code will set the alarm for Monday. How to Set separate alarm for Week days for 8AM and 8PM. How to set Alarm for Week end also. Whether I have to replicate the same above code to set on alarm for each and every day. 
Or else any option to set the alarm in simple manner?

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the alarm to the Monday with a repetition of every 7 days, and make it for the rest of the work days by the same way.

Comment: No Some time I have to set alarm for week end to. So setting of alarm for the whole week wont work.